# How to get images from Blizzard Community Platform

Tags: api

We can get some information by json.
But how can i get images by the information in json.
e.g. "thumbnail": "medivh/1/1-avatar.jpg"
It does not work when i concat the url behind the host + request.
So, is there some other way to get images?

Answer (score 0):

The url for the static images has the following format:

http:// REGION . battle.net/static-render/ REGION / THUMBNAIL

Example:

For the avatar image

```
http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/alexstrasza/57/51685945-avatar.jpg
```

The picture you see when you visit your armory profile

```
http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/alexstrasza/57/51685945-profilemain.jpg
```

Another angle, I don't know where this is used

```
http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/alexstrasza/57/51685945-inset.jpg
```

Comment: it seems this information is well outdated, looking for new info

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest changes to the static renderer, the following is correct:

`http://render-<Region>.worldofwarcraft.com/character/<Thumbnail>`

For example:

`http://render-us.worldofwarcraft.com/character/kul-tiras/148/130814612-profilemain.jpg`